# Directing a user to an external sharepoint site and embedding their link in the form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, hyperlink

I have a requirement to allow users to attach numerous larger files to an infopath form.  Due to size constraints, I have embedded a link within the infopath form to an external sharepoint site where they can upload their file(s).  Now, I'd like to be able to log a reference to the file(s) they uploaded back to the form when they save them on the external sharepoint site.  This way, the next user opening the infopath form can simply click on the link and open the file(s) the user uploaded on the external site.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!
Erin

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a query string on to the upload dialog and use a custom script embedded in the upload dialog to add some type of identifier to the document.  You could then add a secondary data source to the library and define some rules around that identifier.

If you create a custom upload form you can add fields (hidden or otherwise) that can just update MetaData on the library and not modify the user input value at all.  That would actually make it easier to use as a secondary data source without trying to parse strings with the rules.

After many trials with InfoPath over the years - I try to skip it all together if possible.